# Disabling Java auto update notification in ubuntu?

Tags: updates, java, notification

I am looking for a way in ubuntu to disable the Java/JRE update notification so users do not get asked to allow or delay a JRE update.  I would like to have it not check at all so it is not possible for users who do not know how to install it to even have the choice.  I would rather do a manual schedule as needed. I am running Oracle JRE 1.7.0_xx with Firefox.  The update notification is the pop up box that comes up when you start a java applet and it checks to see if you are running the most current version or not.  What I would like to disable if possible is the auto check that is run when the applet is started so the update box does not appear.

Comment: What java auto update notification? Are you running the Oracle JRE, rather than the OpenJDK JRE which is included in Ubuntu? Please update your question with more information about what you are actually running.

Comment: That notification is done on your browser level via a javascrip or similar, has nothing to do with your system itself. To disable that you would need to ask the site that shows you that warning, some web interfaces allow that option.

Comment: This seems to be a Chrome/Chromium feature. See http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1247383 for a possible fix in Chrome.